# Adding letters from a string array into each dynamic div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add each letter of a word to dynamically generated divs `.box` and `.boxIn` but the code is just adding the last word to each box! How can I fix this, and why is his happening? And is there any way to merge two loops into one loop?

[Here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/exkLsmdb/)

And this is the code which I have:

```
var letters = [];
var str = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z";
var letters = str.split(",");
var word = "Test App";
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    $('<div class="box"><div class="boxIn"></div></div>').appendTo(".wrapper");
}

for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
    $('.boxIn').html(word.charAt(j)).addClass('animated fadeInDown');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairly simple to combine these which will make it more efficieent and get rid of the html over ride bug you have

```
var letters = [];
var str = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z";
var letters = str.split(",");
var word = "Test App";
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    $('<div class="box"><div class="boxIn animated fadeInDown">'+
              word.charAt(i)+'</div></div>').appendTo(".wrapper");
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/exkLsmdb/2/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

That's because you are overriding html content of all the `.boxIn` elements, you should use the current iterator's index for selecting the target element:

```
$('.boxIn').eq(j).html(word.charAt(j)).addClass('animated fadeInDown');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k4spypqj/

That being said there is no need to use 2 loops. You can set the generated element's content in the first loop using either `text` or `html` method.

Comment: Thanks undefined ! :-) but, isnt enough to use another variable like j in the iterator?

Comment: @MonaCoder You are welcome! Unfortunately I didn't understand the question in your comment. Actually the second loop is unnecessary. Doing this in the first loop is more efficient. This way there is no need to query the whole DOM in each iteration, at least you can cache the `$('.boxIn')` collection before the second loop, then `$collection.eq(j)...`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way you set the html. You select all elements with the class boxIn and set the char at position j to the html (of all elements).
To only set the char to to a single element you can limit the selection by using the `.eq()` function.

In your case that would be:

```
for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
    $('.boxIn').eq(j).html(word.charAt(j)).addClass('animated fadeInDown');
}
```

If you want to merge your two loops, you can set the value directly in your html string:
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    $('' + word.charAt(i) + '').appendTo(".wrapper").children('.boxIn').addClass('animated fadeInDown');
}

or if you would add it separatly:

```
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    $('<div class="box"><div class="boxIn"></div></div>').appendTo(".wrapper").children('.boxIn').addClass('animated fadeInDown').html(word.charAt(i));
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exkLsmdb/4/)

Comment: Thanks Benjamin but you are adding animation to .box divs as well